# Pass a value from child.master to parent.master

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass a string value from the child.master to the parent.master. There is a function in parent.master

```
public void setMyString(string s)
{
myLiteral.Text = s;
}
```

How can I access such method from my child.master?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the Child.master's Master to the Parent.master's class in order to call a method of that class.

Let's say the class name of the Parent.master is "ParentMasterPage". In Child.master, you can make a call like this:

```
((ParentMasterPage)this.Master).setMyString(param);
```

Comment: I have the following
 public partial class Themes_Default_Options_Confirmation : System.Web.UI.MasterPage so I have to use the whole thing?. When I cast it it says" are you missing a using directive"

Comment: @SuperUser555 Is that the child or parent?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You actually have to cast the Master, not the Parent, so your code in the child would look like this:
((Themes_Default_Options_Confirmation)this.Master).setMyString(param);

Comment: is there a using directive I am missing, it can not find the Themes_Default.... ?

Comment: I think I probably did not provide full data hopefully you understand... so basically there is a usercontrol and this where I am coding this, the user control is placed in a MasterPage that Inherits the Parent.master so in the usercontrol I declared something like .... MasterPage myMasterPage = this.Parent.Parent.Page.Master.Master; I am able to use mymasterPage to pass values to the asp of the parent.master but now I want to pass it to a function in the master.cs

Comment: Since you are trying to access this from a User Control, you will need to add a reference to the master page within the .ascx, like this:
<%@ Reference Control="~/Parent.master" %>

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to call the parent function of the class, either don't overwrite it in the child class, or call the base method in the child function.

If you want to call the parent function of a specific instance of that parent class, then you'll need to have a reference to that instance in the child class instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice don't depend on the some Parent component at all, just image that in the future you decide to paste between child and parent master page some other master page - and you will have a trouble because of the reference to ex-parent master page.

So, in my opinion, it is better to define an event on childmaster page and have an event handler to this event on parent master page.